# Inhouse widgets?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some of the other SE sites have some real formatting wizardry going on: chess allows for move by move playback in the post, others have video embedding features.

Although not all posts on WB would necessitate seeing something like a map, it would be an interesting way to take the direction of development of this site. The point stands that "world" is in the name. I'm imagining some kind of open source tool that is easy to work with, design and embed. Can show planet-scale or zoomed in versions. This way the text within questions won't have to be so exhaustive; everyone could see where there is water, trees, mountains, ect.

But, looking at our most popular tags, [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based),[creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design),[technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) and so forth, maps don't seem to be a good fit.

Perhaps something more general, like wireframes or blueprints? I think there is an open CAD-like google sketch service.

Or, and I realize I'm being cripplingly naive here, but maybe we could have wireframes *and* maps!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a good business case here:

- Worldbuilding is not the most frequented community in SE
- map related questions are not the most frequently asked questions on WB

Putting developers work into something that is scarcely used in a relatively small community can hardly make it to the top of any sprint list.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm sure billions of users are clamouring for move-by-move chess formatting! /jk

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think any widget that enhances the experience of both querent and respondent in this forum ought to be implemented.

- Video embedding looks like a natural -- [This answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/234630/37029) is case in point!
- Audio embedding sounds like it should be a good idea as well
- Something that allows images to be zoomed in and out within the frame might be nice as well.
- Since you mention formatting, we could probably do with some nice templates (ACS, looking at you!) and some advanced formatting features that would improve the aesthetics and readability of our forum